# How do you extract a string that is in between a char/string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, extract

Let's say I have a simple string:

```
string example = "phone number: XXXXXXX,"
```

where X are random values given to me, so they are always different.
How do I extract only the X's?
 `"phone number: "` doesn't change.

what I have now (using Thomas Matthews technique below)

```
const char search_text[] = "phone number: ";
std::string::size_type start_posn = example.find(search_text);
std::string::size_type end_posn = example.find(",", start_posn);
const unsigned int length = end_posn - start_posn - sizeof(search_text) - 1;
cout << "length: " << length << endl;
std::string data = example.substr(start_posn, length);
cout << data << endl;
```

what if I had `string example = "phone number: XXXXXXX, Date: XXXXXXXX,"`?

Comment: take a look to [Regular Expression] (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/)

Comment: Search stackoverflow.com first, before posting your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20extract%20string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, looks like you would search for "phone number: " and then determine the index or position after the phrase.  Your requirements infer that there is a "," after the data you want.

So, you want the `substr`ing between the ": " and before the ",".  In the olden days, we would search for the "," and get its position.  The number of characters to extract is obtained by subtracting the two indices:
**Edit 1**

```
const char search_text[] = "phone number: ";
std::string::size_type start_posn = example.find(search_text);
if (start_posn != std::string::npos)
{
   start_posn += sizeof(search_text) - 1;
}
std::string::size_type end_posn   = example.find(",", start_posn);
const unsigned int length = end_posn - start_posn;
std::string data = example.substr(start_posn, length);
```

Note:  the above code does not handle error cases where the `find` method returns `std::string::npos`.

Using the above technique, how would you extract the data after "Date: "?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am still thinking about your question.
 what if i have something like `"phone number: XXXXXXX, phone number: XXXXXXX,"` 
how do you get the second one but not the first?

Comment: Ignore the first scan and scan again.  Think.

Comment: Using your way i still get `phone number: XXXXXXX` the comma is gone but `phone number: ` is still there.

Comment: You need to add the length of "phone number: " to the starting position.

Comment: Yup I switched the length to 7 and it gave me the 7 first characters of the string `phone n`.

Comment: See my Edit 1.  I declare the search text as a constant string and use it's length to calculate the position.  The "-1" is to account for the terminating nul character in the search text.